# Is it possible to force IP source depending on source ports?

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a question about routing. I've searched the Internet, found some hints but couldn't make it work.

I have a server with 2 public IP and the same gateway. Let's say 1.1.1.1 (on eth0) and 1.1.1.2 (on eth0:0) and gateway is 1.1.1.254 (network /24).

There is a second server (not mine) with IP 2.2.2.2/24.

Between those 2 servers, I have radius and http flux.

Right now all the flux from my server to the other server originates from the IP 1.1.1.1. Please also note that Radius listen on IP 1.1.1.2 and port 1812 and 1813 (both UDP).

What I want to do is that only the packet originating from Radius ports are sent with source IP 1.1.1.2. All HTTP traffic must originates from 1.1.1.1 as before.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask your radius server to bind to 1.1.1.2 only.
That way it will only communicate with IP 1.1.1.2.  That's exactly why `bind()` is designed for.

Note that on Linux, `bind()` does not restrict which network interface can be used to communicate. It just restricts what IP address can be used.

Of course, if a client connects to 1.1.1.1 anyway, it will be rejected. But this communication cannot work anyway: If you reply as 1.1.1.2 anyway, the host that contacted 1.1.1.1 will not recognise that the two IP belong to the same host.

---

Also your post suggest that you are using `ifconfig` and interface aliases.  Please note that `ifconfig` is obsolete and interface aliases are seriously deprecated.  The kernel have the native functionality to add several IP address to an interface since ages, and this interface alias thing is just a compatibility layer for old applications like `ifconfig`. Please use `ip` from the iproute2 package.  `ìp addr` and `ip route` will show you the true configuration of your network interfaces.

Comment: Right now Radius already listen only on the desired IP (1.1.1.2). However it seems that the packets sent by my server arrives on the other server with the wrong IP (1.1.1.1). Which looks weird, I agree.

Comment: If your server sends packets with the correct source address (verified via tcpdump/*shark, i presume) but your other server receives them with a wrong IP, then there is something in the middle that modifies it, and your server cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary and secondary IPs on an interface, connections *originating* from that machine use the primary IP by default. I don't think you can change that easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I did edit my first post. It wasn't clear enough. There is one IP on eth0 (the current default IP) and a second one on eth0:0.

Comment: Yeah, it's as I described, a secondary address.

Comment: OK, "unfortunately" you understood correctly my problem :) Thanks a lot for your time.